# error en migración con Django Multitenant

Tags: django

Saludos tengo una app con [django-db-multitenant](https://github.com/mik3y/django-db-multitenant) la cual funciona bien el problema surge al tratar de realizar una migración:

```
TENANT_DATABASE_NAME=rg python manage.py migrate
```

Con **makemigrations** funciona bien se genera el archivo .py, el problema surge al colocar el migrate, el error que genera:

```
[roo@rgmanagement_2 facturacion]$ TENANT_DATABASE_NAME=rg python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: correo, empresa, sessions, personal, admin, proveedores, ordenescompra, seguridad, auth, cartera, bodegas, movimientos, contenttypes, custodias, clientes, contabilidad, productos, secuencias, ordenespedido, ventas
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying seguridad.0004_auto_20190709_1300...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 202, in database_forwards
    new_model._meta.db_table,
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 359, in alter_db_table
    "new_table": self.quote_name(new_db_table),
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 112, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 165, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 321, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 860, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1061, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1349, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1018, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 384, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.InternalError: (1017, u"Can't find file: './rg/seguridad_configuracioninicial.frm' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)")
```

Tengo agregado las configuraciones respectivas tal cual indica en la documentación

[Management Commands](https://github.com/mik3y/django-db-multitenant#management-commands)

uso esta versión de Django Multitenant para usarlo con MySql dado que las otras son para Oracle ó PostgreSql.

Quizá alguna sugerencia gracias de antemano.

Comment: elimina la carpeta migrations, generalas de nuevo y ejecuta el comando, probablemente hicistes tantos cambios en el modelo que el `seguridad.0004_auto_20190709_1300` te da problema de relacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin duda me ayudo el comentario de **JackNavaRow** .

Para resolver dicho problema lo que hice fue eliminar el archivo en conflicto de la carpeta `migrations` de mi `app`.

Adicional a esto `Django` por defecto posee una tabla `django_migrations` en la cual registra las migraciones realizadas, por ende también eliminé dicho registro que causaba conflictos y con esto realicé nuevamente el `migrate` con éxito.

Espero a alguien mas le sirva..!!